# Change default iOS slider

Tags: ios, uislider

How can i change the default slider in iOS?

By this i mean making the slider thicker and the knob larger.

Is it even possible or am i forced to create a custom slider?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes with iOS5 you can use the appearance protocol. Or directly manipulate the UISlider. Have a look at the documentation, there are several appearance methods to replace the graphics for the bars & the knob.

Comment: But its not possible to resize the default graphics?

Comment: Those examples were enough to change my sliders, thanks alot.

Answer (score 1):

These nifty components might also help:
http://cocoacontrols.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=slider

Comment: Very interesting knobs! Thanks alot for the link.

Answer (score 0):

jaydee3 is exactly right: use the appearance method to modify your UI controls application-wide.

If you want a specific tutorial on customizing the appearance of your sliders, including how to create your own images for them, I wrote this article about how to do that on my company's website:

http://www.fragmentlabs.com/blog/making-talking2trees-part-1-75

There's also a [Demo Project](http://www.fragmentlabs.com/files/blogs/CustomSliderDemo_Part1.zip) I created for this, too. Check the AppDelegate.m for the applicable code.